# How to convert a 1:1 relation into a 1:N relation

Tags: sql-server, ddl

I've got a db SQL not well implemented and a few questions.

1.the fk doesn't seems to work well i've to make separated queries to add a value in all the tables,

2. the first table it's strange but is correct,it has to be separated from the others(i've to add,cancel,modify)simultaneously in tab  tabList and tabSE.
3. i've to implement a relation 1:N between tabSE and tabSD(don't know how to do that) practically the goal is to select(form c# bla bla bla) a bunch of items,click start and store the info that in the day mm/dd/yyyy i've started the items(by clicking on the buttonStart) with id (1,5,3,6,8) for example and the start have got a result bla bla bla, and it's ended the day mm/dd/yyyy. I think that maybe Union is meaningless and from tabSD maybe the NomeI don't have to exist,don't know. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top to bottom:

1. If you have an FK between tabStoreExec and tabStoricoDetail, the only 2 things you can do automatically are **UPDATE** and **DELETE** with the keyword (or option configuring the table) **CASCADE**
2. I suppose this is a "temporary" table used as back for the interface utility.
3. For making the 1:N. I think the best is **delete table Union**, then you must **create a composite key on tabStoricoDetail**, like id and idDetail for example, and let the FK make his job linking just the id's of both tables:

   ```
   tabStoreExec.idSE -> tabStoricoDetail.id
   ```

I give you some **CREATE TABLES** code example that will work as you wish:

```
CREATE TABLE tabStoreExec (
    idSE INT --PRIMARY KEY --Coul be done here, but can't be named
    , nomeItem VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL --or maybe could be NULL
    , DateStarSE DATE --or DATETIME, depends if you want the time too
    , DateEndSE DATE
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tabStoreExec PRIMARY KEY (id)
    , CONSTRAINT FK_tabStoreExec_idSE_id FOREIGN KEY (idSE) REFERENCES tabStoricoDetail(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE --use this in case you want to propagate the delete/update action from this table to referenced.
);

CREATE TABLE tabStoricoDetail (
    id INT
    , idDetail INT
    , nomeItem VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL --or maybe could be NULL
    , resItemDet VARCHAR(100)
    , CONSTRAINT PK_tabStoricoDetail PRIMARY KEY (id, idDetail)
);
```

I hope this could be helpful to you.

**Edit:**
Yes, Union table can be disappear.

The FK is the "connector" between both tables, it gives you the data integrity, and the composite PK is to can have the 1:N relation. I give you here a sample schema for better help:

[Sample Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr2Ra.png)

Comment: thank you,for the answer i was starting to loose hope. so Union do you think that can vanish? and then the fk between idSE and id and  for implement the 1:N? what have i to connect?

Comment: sorry for the odd question just want to be sure before touching the db cause i don't know ho to go back :')

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (id, idDetail) do not understand how or where is link between TSE and TSD id and idDetail are declared only in tsd

Comment: could you  give me some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you should limit your post to a single question, not multiples. Such a post is difficult to discuss in a forum. Your question also span many different areas. I suggest you focus on a specific area first - in particular the schema. Once the schema is address you can then begin to define the interface you wish to provide.

And comments like "doesn't seem to work well" are not useful. The only person that understands that in any detail is YOU.

At this point, your schema implements a M:M relationship between tabStoreExec and tabStoricoDetail. And for the love of future generations, really REALLY give your naming standards some consideration. You don't need a naming standard where the object type is the first part of every name IMO. No idea what "StoreExec" means either. /Rant

But before going further, explain why you created the table "Union" (another poor naming choice). That junction table is the mechanism used to implement a M:M relationship. Was there a reason for this? Did you change your mind? Some other difficulty?

If you want a 1:M relationship, you should remove that table and simply add a foreign key column in tabStoricoDetail to tabStoreExec. I suggest you examine the sample databases Microsoft has created for demonstrating SQL Server functionality - [AdventureWorks and World Wide Importers](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases). AdventureWorks was originally developed for 2005 version but is still a common reference. Use these are examples of how to define schemas.

Comment: the question to your answer is how?should i add another column built to be a fk?

Comment: the answer that you gave to me is wrong, the relation is M:1 because each chosen items from TSE  have a result, i've to create a summarized result from the sum of the result of the items and put it into TSD so the answer is wrong